# Selecting MongoDB or DynamoDB pricing

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm developing a website that reads JSON objects from a database but I'm unsure whether to use the following:

1. MongoLab/MongoHQ MongoDB or
2. Amazon's DynamoDB

My concerns are how does the pricing compare.  With DynamoDB, the free usage tier is 25 reads a second.  How many web users will this allow me who hit the search to read from Dynamo.  Does MongoLab or MongoHQs' MongoDb offer a flat fee and disregard the number of IOs i.e. read and writes??

Technically speaking, the database items will need to be updated every week.  With DynamoDB, the simplest way is to delete the whole table and recreate it.  How would you delete items in MongoDB and would there be a penalty in terms of cost and performance??

AWS DynamoDB has released a new plan in Oct 2014 but is it now more favorable than MongoDB?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. Without an _exact_ use case description, some (quite a lot of) code to look at and some data on your users, this question is impossible to answer. and with the mentioned data, you'd need an answer which is out of scope of SO. My suggestion would be to hire a big data consultant, as there are _a lot_ of perspectives one has to take to answer this question thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Since This question remains unanswered possibly because the options are too costly.  The best solution I found was AWS simpleDB which is a fraction of the cost.

Both dynamodb and simpleDB do not conform to the ACID test so are unsuitable where consistency or security such as payments need conforming.  Not to sound like I'm on an ACID trip, they both conform to the BASE principals (Basically available, soft state && eventually consistent).  Since my goal was to load a object list, consistency was never a big issue but I've learnt that dynamodb make it very difficult to batch delete items and their charges for simple reads is through the roof and you can only query 1MB worth of data per call.

A website works best with some aspects being not only SQL (noSQL) and some (SQL) which was not mentioned by anyone.

AWS SimpleDB can suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've found MongoDB to be reasonably priced if you install it yourself as opposed to installing from the AMI marketplace. See the [answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037720/deploying-a-node-js-app-that-uses-mongo-db-on-aws/28307784#28307784)